# Use an inner.HTML mathematically?

Tags: javascript, math, numbers, innerhtml

I'm making a script, in which i have to use an inner.HTML which is a number, and work with it mathematically. Here's the example:

```
<span id="searchResults">2301</span>
```

As you can see, the inner.HTML is a number, and I'd like to make a script like:

```
var results = document.getElementById("searchResults");
if (results > 3000)
    {
        location.reload(true);
    }
```

Of course this isn't possible because the script doesn't see the inner.HTML as a number it can mathematically work with.

So, is there a way to convert the inner.HTML into a number I can do math with?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You could use the `parseInt` function.

Comment: `inner.HTML` should be `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use unary operator `+` for convert string to number something like

```
var results = +(document.getElementById("searchResults").innerHTML);
//------------^
```

Also you forgot to use `.innerHTML`

Comment: This works, but is not easy and straight forward when reading.

Comment: @KrisKrause, I think it's better than before, is not?

Comment: @bram, always there for contribute.:)

Answer (score 2):

You probably need `.innerHTML`, as without `.innerHTML` your `results` will contain `HTMLspanobject` you have to do `innerHTML`

```
var results = document.getElementById("searchResults").innerHTML;
alert(parseInt(results));
if (parseInt(results,10) > 3000)
{
    alert("te");
   // location.reload(true);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/93kpu/1/)

Comment: what does the ",10" mean?

Comment: @bram It's a radix, Have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: If you leave out the radix parameter, it's possible that some numbers with leading zeroes will be interpreted as octal values instead of decimal.

Comment: @nderscore Not sure but [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) is there as an option!

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to actually get the innerHTML (you are currently looking at the HTML element node)
2. You can use `parseInt`, `parseFloat` or the Unary `+` Operator (but you probably don't need to since `>` is quite smart when the LHS is a number).

Such:

```
var results = document.getElementById("searchResults");
var results_num = parseInt( results.innerHTML, 10 );
```

Comment: Props for using `10` as the second parameter for parseInt to avoid accidental octal integer parsing.

Comment: @thanks and +1 for lable `Unary Operator`, did not know exact word when was using `+` in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = document.getElementById("searchResults").innerHTML;
if (parseInt(results) > 3000)
{
    location.reload(true);
}
```

InnerHtml returns string content. You need to convert it to a number/integer.

Comment: It will be the same. You will need parseInt

Comment: It will return `isNan`, Condition will never get `true`!

Comment: isNan is 'is not a number' - try doing typeof() and let me know what it is

Comment: Look at the solution below. I forgot the null check

Comment: You forgot `.innerHTML`.

Comment: One more typo. You need to drop the `()` since `.innerHTML` isn't a function

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = document.getElementById("searchResults");
if (results != null && parseInt(results.innerHTML) > 3000)
{
  location.reload(true);
}
```

Comment: Please confirm you do NOT have multiple tags with searchResults id.

Comment: syntax says "missing radix parameter"

Comment: The radix is technically optional, it is just bad practise to leave it out. The problem with this code is that `results` isn't a number (or a string representation of a number).

Comment: radix is required?  Since when?  As of ECMAScript 5, the default is the decimal radix (10).

Comment: The result of passing a DOM node to `parseInt` will be `NaN`.