# Is there a way to use a element innerHTML as keyCode number?

Tags: jquery, html, tampermonkey

The title says it, I was wondering if it's possible to use an innerHTML as a keyCode value, for example:

```
if (event.keyCode == 65) { 
        thing1();
        thing2();
}
```

Is there a way to get an element's innerHTML and use it instead of "65"? For example, you make a clickable box that registers any key you press and converts it into a keyCode number to use instead of "65"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22766201/use-an-inner-html-mathematically/22766221#22766221

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. As you've tagged this question with jQuery only you would be better off using the `text()` method instead of `html()` or `innerHTML`, and then converting it to an integer before making the comparison.  Try this:

```js
var keycode = parseInt($('span').text(), 10);

$('#foo').on('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === keycode) {
    console.log(`You pressed '${String.fromCharCode(keycode)}', keycode: ${e.keyCode}`);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Keycode: <span>97</span>
</p>

<p>
  Press 'a' in this field:
  <input type="text" id="foo" />
</p>
```

Comment: Probably will work, but I'm pretty new to this whole coding thing. Nothing happens for me in the code snippet so I'm trying to understand the code.

Comment: Note that I made the example use keycode 13, which is an enter keypress

Comment: Ohhh I see now!

Comment: Would there be a way to display any key you type in that box? Other than choosing a specific key?

Comment: Sure, you can use `String.fromCharCode()`. I updated the answer for you, note that' it's now an `a` you need to press as you need to use a printable character for anything to be displayed